# Data Conversion from SQL, C# with Linq to JSON for Highcharts Line chart

Tags: c#, json, highcharts

I am looking to convert the below SQL results into a JSON list for a Highcharts line chart. I am using C#. I cant get my head around how I would create an appropriate class(es) and populate them with this data in the format needed.

```
ID  Name    Month   Year    Data
2   Name 1  10      2015    4
2   Name 1  11      2015    5
2   Name 1  12      2015    6
3   Name 2  10      2015    6
3   Name 2  11      2015    7
3   Name 2  12      2015    8
4   Name 3  10      2015    35
4   Name 3  11      2015    7
4   Name 3  12      2015    8
```

The end result needs to be in something like this format. The ID and year also need to come through but are used for different things. Can this be done?

```
categories: ['10', '11', '12'],....
series: [{
        name: 'Name 1',
        data: [4, 5, 6]
    }, {
        name: 'Name 2',
        data: [6, 7, 8]
    }, {
        name: 'Name 3',
        data: [35, 7, 8]
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ro = new RootObject();
        ro.AddRow(1, "Name1", 2015, 10, 4);
        ro.AddRow(1, "Name1", 2015, 11, 5);
        ro.AddRow(1, "Name1", 2015, 12, 6);

        ro.AddRow(2, "Name2", 2015, 10, 6);
        ro.AddRow(2, "Name2", 2015, 11, 7);
        ro.AddRow(2, "Name2", 2015, 12, 8);

        ro.AddRow(3, "Name3", 2015, 10, 35);
        ro.AddRow(3, "Name3", 2015, 11, 7);
        ro.AddRow(3, "Name3", 2015, 12, 8);

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ro);
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        //Output:
        //{
        //    "categories":[10,11,12],
        //    "series":[
        //        {"name":"Name1","data":[4,5,6]},
        //        {"name":"Name2","data":[6,7,8]},
        //        {"name":"Name3","data":[35,7,8]}]
        //}

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public RootObject()
        {
            categories = new List<int>();
            series = new List<Series>();
        }

        public void AddRow(int id, string name, int year, int month, int data)
        {
            if (!categories.Contains(month))
            {
                categories.Add(month);
            }

            var serie = series.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == name);
            if (serie == null)
            {
                serie = new Series(name);
                series.Add(serie);
            }
            serie.data.Add(data);
        }

        public List<int> categories { get; set; }
        public List<Series> series { get; set; }
    }

    public class Series
    {
        public Series(string _name)
        {
            name = _name;
            data = new List<int>();
        }

        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<int> data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I then add the data to the classes?

Comment: I edited the answer, with a full working exempel. Paste the code in to a console application and use nuget to install Newtonsoft.Json. (Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json) or JSON serializer by choice.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: That has been really helpful, it's not something I've considered before so I should be able to implement this in other things.